# How to get Playwright browser tests running on Alpine Docker container?

Tags: java, docker, automated-tests, playwright, alpine-linux

The Java drivers that come with Playwright don't work with Alpine, because they don't use statically linked MUSL builds.

Answer (score 5):

In your Alpine image, install `nodejs` and `chromium` from Alpine repositories and set env vars that tell Playwright to use them instead of its own drivers:

```
echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" > /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community" \
    && apk upgrade -U -a \
    && apk add \
    libstdc++ \
    chromium \
    harfbuzz \
    nss \
    freetype \
    ttf-freefont \
    font-noto-emoji \
    wqy-zenhei \
    nodejs \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/* \
    && mkdir /var/cache/apk

export PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1
export PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
export PLAYWRIGHT_NODEJS_PATH=/usr/bin/node
```

Then, in your Java or Kotlin code you have to handle the custom browser location yourself:

```
abstract class AbstractBrowserTest(private val headless: Boolean = true) {

    private val playwright: Playwright = Playwright.create()
    private val browser: Browser = launchBrowser()

    private fun launchBrowser(): Browser {
        val env = System.getenv("PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH")
        return if (env != null && env.isNotBlank()) {
            playwright.chromium().launch(LaunchOptions().setHeadless(true).setExecutablePath(Paths.get(env)))
        } else {
            playwright.chromium().launch(LaunchOptions().setHeadless(headless))
        }
    }
}
```

Props to https://github.com/fivemru/playwright-docker-alpine for inspiration!